# Textfield to scroll up automatically above virtual keyboard

Tags: blackberry, java-me, lwuit

The issue that I face in my bblwuit app is this:

I have a textfield, when clicking on it the virtual keyboard opens, which is fine.  However, the text field is hidden behind the keyboard.  How do I make the screen scroll automatically so that the textfield is visible above the virtual keyboard?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this

```
VerticalFieldManager vfm=new VerticalFieldManager(VERTICAL_SCROLL);
BasicEditField bef=new BasicEditField();
vfm.add(bef);
add(vfm);
```

Comment: the way in which you have told is for native bb can you tell me a way in which whn the vkb opens the cursor in the focus text field automatically scrolls up for LWUIT BB